# ErrorException When Registering with Laravel 8 Jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I started a project on Laravel 7 just before the launch of Laravel 8, I am still learning this framework, so I updated to that version using this steps, and I am aware of this new scaffolding library call Jetstream that I installed with these steps:

1. `composer require laravel/jetstream`
2. `php artisan jetstream:install livewire --teams`
3. `npm install && npm run dev`
4. `php artisan migrate`

After working on my views and models I am proceeding to implement sessions functionalities, but when I tried to register with the project at localhost:8000/register, and having my data validated I get this error

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: \path-to\my-project\resources\views\navigation-dropdown.blade.php) (View: \path-to\my-project\resources\views\navigation-dropdown.blade.php) (View: \path-to\my-project\resources\views\navigation-dropdown.blade.php)
> http://localhost:8000/dashboard

This is the section of view that is throwing the exception
navigation-dropdown.blade.php line 169 this is the vanilla file

```
                    <!-- Team Settings -->
                <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="{{ route('teams.show', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id) }}" :active="request()->routeIs('teams.show')">
                    {{ __('Team Settings') }}
                </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>
```

The data introduced in the register form gets stored in the database, but the error happens

I checked this other question [Laravel Jetstream + Livewire + Teams FeatureTest problems when authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111011/laravel-jetstream-livewire-teams-featuretest-problems-when-authenticate) but it seems that answer apply to a different context since it is dealing with tests, no the vanilla register functions.

This is my current composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried installing to test a fresh Laravel project with Jetstream, and this worked as it should, that let me confused as to what happened with my current project.

Comment: look at the view file and figure out why it is trying to get the 'id' property of something ... perhaps this is a route that needs to be behind auth and that view is trying to get the authenticated user's id?

Comment: In the view it seems that is requesting the current Team ID, I installed the teams libraries for Jetstream, but like I said in a fresh install it works, so it should work here.

Comment: then the user may not be associated with a team

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what worked for me was create a new fresh project with jetstream, then in my original project deleted the vendor and node_modules folder then copying the files of the new fresh project unto my original project and now it works as expected

<sub>*Answer added on behalf of OP.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The user was not created with a team assigned, see users table and column current_team_id is null.
The navigation-menu.blade.php checks only for TeamFeatures but not if a team is really assigned.

```
            @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures())
            @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures() && Auth::user()->current_team_id)
```

For details here is the issue [trying to get property of non-object](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/issues/376)